# Usefulness of "function arrows associate to the right"?

Tags: haskell

Reading http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/lectures/04-higher-order.html it states

> In particular, note that function arrows associate to the right, that
>   is, W -> X -> Y -> Z is equivalent to W -> (X -> (Y -> Z)). We can
>   always add or remove parentheses around the rightmost top-level arrow
>   in a type.

Function arrows associate to the right but as function application associates to the left then what is usefulness of this information ? I feel I'm not understanding something as to me it is a meaningless point that function arrows associate to the right. As function application always associates to the left then this the only associativity I should be concerned with ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Function arrows associate to the right but [...] what is usefulness of this information?

If you see a type signature like, for example, `f : String -> Int -> Bool` you need to know the associativity of the function arrow to understand what the type of `f` really is:

1. if the arrow associates to the left, then the type means `(String -> Int) -> Bool`, that is, `f` takes a function as argument and returns a boolean.
2. if the arrow associates to the right, then the type means `String -> (Int -> Bool)`, that is, `f` takes a string as argument and returns a function.

That's a big difference, and if you want to use `f`, you need to know which one it is. Since the function arrow associates to the right, you know that it has to be the second option: `f` takes a string and returns a function.

> Function arrows associate to the right [...] function application associates to the left

These two choices work well together. For example, we can call the `f` from above as `f "answer" 42` which really means `(f "answer") 42`. So we are passing the string `"answer"` to `f` which returns a function. And then we're passing the number `42` to that function, which returns a boolean. In effect, we're almost using `f` as a function with two arguments.

This is the standard way of writing functions with two (or more) arguments in Haskell, so it is a very common use case. Because of the associativity of function application and of the function arrow, we can write this common use case without parentheses.

Comment: This also helps you to think about the useful technique of [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), whereby we use the actual _function_ that is returned.  For example, if we had some `f x y : Int -> Int -> Int` that calculated `x * y`, then we could use `f 2` as a "doubling" function, of `f 3` as a "tripling" function etc

Answer (score 6):

When defining a two-argument curried function, we usually write something like this:

```
f :: a -> b -> c
f x y = ...
```

If the arrow did not associate to the right, the above type would instead have to be spelled out as `a -> (b -> c)`. So the usefulness of `->`'s associativity is that it saves us from writing too many parentheses when declaring function types.

Answer (score 1):

If an operator `#` is 'right associative', it means this:

```
a # b # c # d  =  a # (b # (c # d))
```

... for any number of arguments. It behaves like `foldr`

This means that:

```
a -> b -> c -> d  =  a -> (b -> (c -> d))
```

*Note: `a -> (b -> (c -> d)) =/= ((a -> b) -> c) -> d` ! This is very important.*

What this tells us is that, say, `foldr`:

```
λ> :t foldr
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

Takes a function of type `(a -> b -> b)`, and then returns... a function that takes a `b`, and then returns... a function that takes a `[a]`, and then returns... a `b`. This means that we can apply functions like this

```
f a b c
```

because

```
f a b c  =  ((f a) b) c
```

and `f` will return two functions each time an argument is given.

Essentially, this isn't very *useful* as such, but is important information for when we want to interpret and call function types.

However, in functions like `(++)`, associativity matters. If `(++)` were left associative, it would be very slow, so it's right associative.

Comment: (++) function application associates to the right, which has performance implications as you mention and so is useful information. The associativity of the arrows is meaningless and has no use as function application is all that matters ?

Comment: 'However, in functions like (++), associativity matters. If (++) were left associative, it would be very slow, so it's right associative.' That's a bit of a misleading statement. If I have something like `a ++ b ++ c` there's a fast way to parenthesize it and a slow way. Associativity affects which one is chosen *if I don't parenthesize it myself*, but it does not affect the speed of the function itself. If I fully parenthesize my use of an operator, associativity has no effect at all.

Comment: @blue-sky `a -> (b -> c)` is a very different type from `(a -> b) -> c`, so when you write `a -> b -> c`, it's not meaningless at all what the associativity of `->` is.

Comment: @sepp2k type with signature (a -> b) -> c . (a -> b) will be evaluated first then the result of this evaluation will be evaluated with c . In this case function application associates to right instead of default associativity to left if no parenthesis used ?

Comment: @blue-sky Types aren't expressions, they are not evaluated. And even for expressions neither associativity nor use of parentheses tell you which subexpression is evaluated first - they only tell you what the subexpressions are. The difference between `f :: (a -> b) -> c` and `g :: a -> (b -> c)` is that `f` takes a function as its argument (and that function takes an `a` and prodcues a `b`) and produces a result of type `c`, whereas `g` takes an argument of type `a` and produces a function of type `b -> c` as its result (or alternatively you might say it takes two arguments of types `a` ...

Comment: ... and `b` and produces a result of type `c`). That's very different from what `f` does.

Answer (score 0):

Early functional language Lisp suffered from excessively nested parenthesis (which make code (or even text (if you do not mind to consider a broader context)) difficult to read. With time functional language designers opted to make functional code easy to read and write for pros even at cost of confusing rookies with less uniform rules.

In functional code, 
function type declaration like (String -> Int) -> Bool are much more rare than functions like String -> (Int -> Bool), because functions that return functions are trade mark of functional style. Thus associating arrows to right helps reduce parentheses number (on overage, you might need to map a function to a primitive type). For function applications it is vise-versa.

Answer (score 0):

The main purposes is convenience, because partial function application goes from left to right.

Every time you partially apply a function to a set of values, the remaining type has to be valid.

You can think of arrow types as a queue of types, where the queue itself is a type. During partial function application, you dequeue as many types from the queue as the number of arguments, yielding whatever remains of the queue. The resulting queue is still a valid type.

This is why types associate to the right. If types associate to the left, it will behave like a stack, and you won't be able to partially apply it the same way without leaving "holes" or undefined domains. For instance, say you have the following function:

```
foo :: a -> b -> c -> d
```

If Haskell types were left-associative, then passing a single parameter to foo would yield the following invalid type:

```
((? -> b) -> c) -> d
```

You will then be forced to circumvent it by adding parentheses, which could hamper readability.