# What does " Non type-variable argument in the constraint" really mean?

Tags: haskell, type-deduction

For example:

```
map (+1) 2
```

in ghci yields

```
<interactive>:23:1: error:
* Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num [b]
  (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
* When checking the inferred type
    it :: forall b. (Num b, Num [b]) => [b]
```

I've seen many questions similar to mine, but all seem only to answer what we can deduce from this (that the type of the second argument to `map` is wrong), and how to fix it - but not what error actually *means* . Where do things go wrong precisely?

Comment: What happened when you googled the error?

Comment: What happens is that I see, quote, "many questions similar to mine, but all seem only to answer what we can deduce from this (that the type of the second argument to map is wrong), and how to fix it - but not what error actually means."

Comment: I believe [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40895334/2751851) covers most of your question (the type constructor over there was `(->)` rather than `[]`, but the issue is pretty much the same).

Comment: **Since nobody seems to know anymore, what “understanding” actually means, and you, again, got only replies of the type where repeating memorized rules is confused with understanding … (We can thank our “education” system for that) … I added my answer.**
Which was, of course, promptly censored by the Army Of The Offended, who apparently felt spoken to. ^^

Comment: @Evi1M4chine, what was wrong with duplode's response? It seems on point.

Answer (score 4):

The error arises during the type-deduction of your statement.

Since

1. `(+1)` is of type `Num a => a -> a`
2. `2` is of type `Num a => a`
3. `map` is of type `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`

We know that `map (+1)` has to be of type `(Num b) => [b] -> [b]`, and therefore `map (+1) 2` of type `(Num b, Num [b]) => [b]`. But `[b]` is not just a type-variable, it's *List* of some type variable, where list is a *data constructor*. In an alternative version of Haskell where no syntactic sugar for lists exists, we might write `(Num b, Num (List b))`.

This is a problem because by default, Haskell does not support *non type-variable arguments for constraints*. So the precise nature of the problem is not that Haskell doesn't know how to map over numbers - it's that it doesn't allow values of the type that our function call produces.

But that rule isn't strictly needed. By adding `-XFlexibleContexts` when calling ghci, types of the sort that our method produces are now allowed. The reason for this is that the literal `2` in Haskell doesn't really represent a number - it represents an object of type `Num a => a`, which is constructed from the Integral `2` using `fromIntegral`. So the statement `map (+1) 2` is equivalent to `map (+1) (fromIntegral (2::Integer))`. This means that the literal "2" can represent anything, given the proper instantiation - including lists.

Comment: Why would you "fix" this by assigning the result to an unused variable, rather than just eliminating the call in the first place?

Comment: The latter half of this answer is incorrect: the type of the result is not `Num [Integer]`, but more like `Num [Integer] => [Integer]`; and the problem *is* that Haskell does not (by default) know how to map over a single number, and *not* as you claim that it doesn't know how to display the result.

Comment: @DanielWagner ty, corrected it.To the second part: How would you teach it that behaviour, then? You would have to redefine `map`, right? Which I wouldn't consider "teach how to map", rather "change what map means"

Comment: @chepner It's a purely theoretical problem for educational pruposes. I don't know what `map (+1) 2` should produce, even if it worked. It's more about what the error message means / where things go wrong.

Comment: @Nearoo For example, `instance Num a => Num [a] where fromInteger x = [fromInteger x]` would make your `map (+1) 2` "work". But I don't recommend doing that; instead, be more clear about what computation you want to do, as in starting from  `map (+1) [2]` or whatever list you actually meant. `2` is not a list, and teaching the compiler to pretend it is seems like a good way to introduce subtle bugs.

Comment: @DanielWagner interesting. how does this instantiation make it work? That surprises me.

Comment: @Nearoo When you write `2`, the compiler says this has type `Num a => a`. This means that `2` can be any type which has a `Num` instance. Writing `instance Num a => Num [a]` makes a `Num` instance for lists, so that `2` can be interpreted as being a list.

Comment: @DanielWagner okok... let me move this to chat real quick

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209669/discussion-between-nearoo-and-daniel-wagner).

Answer (score 2):

`2` has the type `Num a => a`; we haven't specified what `a` *is*, except that it has to have a `Num` instance.

`map (+1)` has the type `Num b => [b] -> [b]`; we have specified what `b` is, except it has to have a `Num` instance.

When we determine the type of `map (+1) 2`, we are basically unifying `Num a ~ Num b => [b]`.

```
2 ::                  Num a    => a
map (+1) ::    Num b           => [b] -> [b]
map (+1) 2 :: (Num b, Num [b]) =>        [b]
```

And this is the problem. `Num` requires a type variable like `a` or `b`, not a polymorphic type like `[b]`, as its argument.

Answer (score 1):

### Here’s an actual answer:

GHC tries to infer the types by itself, and failed, or in GHC lingo:

```
When checking the inferred type …
```

##### Basically the conflict is:

• GHC is happy to have any value as a parameter for `map (+1)`, as long as it is compatible with its type. And `map (+1)` wants a list of numbers, since `+` wants two numbers and `1` already is one number, and `map` always wants a list of values compatible with that.

• And here’s the kicker: **GHC is happy to have `2` be any type!** Because to save you the hassle of always having to specify if a literal `2` is of a certain type, GHC just treats numeric literals as `Integer` and replaces it with `fromInteger 2`. So since `fromInteger` is from the class `Num`, `2` can be anything that implemented that class `Num`! **So `2` could be a list too!**

So GHC is stuck trying to fit those things together, and tells you:
*“It needs to be some value, that is a number. … And where the list of those values **is also a number**!”*
Or in Haskell:

```
it :: forall b. (Num b, Num [b]) => [b]
```

But there is no instance that makes lists numbers!
Or in GHC lingo:

```
Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num [b]
```

That’s why you nowadays get this, yes definitely badly designed and confusing error message.
(Almost all GHC error messages are a cruel joke. The best thing you can do to understand them, is to read them *bottom to top*! And know all of Haskell’s type system freedoms and the GHC extensions that are forcing GHC to not make assumptions that would make these errors a much simpler sub-class of errors otherwise.)

**Obviously,** you’d normally just replace `2` with an actual list of some sort. But we’re not going to do that here. Since GHC wants crazy, GHC shall get crazy:

##### Silly resolution

So since it leaves us the option of making lists (of numbers) numbers, that’s what we shall do:

```
instance  Num b => Num [b] where
  (+) = zipWith (+)
  (*) = zipWith (*)
  abs = map abs
  signum = map signum
  fromInteger i = [fromInteger i]
  -- or repeat [fromInteger i], if we’re evil. ;)
  negate = map negate
```

So now, it works perfectly fine:

```
>  map (+1) 2
[3]
```

Since `2` becomes `fromInteger 2 :: Num a => [a]`, which puts `2` in a list (`[2]`), and then `map (+1)` is happy and turns it into `[2+1]`. Which evaluates to `[3]`.

**This possibility is *why* the error message wasn’t a much simpler

*“Error: `2` is not a list, but `map` expects a list!”*.**

Comment: If you want even sillier fun, try implementing such classes for *function types*. :D

Comment: Note that this always is only one way one could implement this.  One could implement `Num [a]` in many different ways. None of which being intuitive, since a list is not a number! Hence there being no existing implementation for it.

Comment: (That Haskell allows only one implementation per type, is kinda a big flaw in my eyes. And it stems from the same problem that the greybearded highland philosophers of Haskell expect that what every function does is completely documented by its type. … So I guess `(+)` and `(-)` do the same thing. right? XD …  
Of course outside of the ivory towers, we actually have to implement specific things. And their answer to that is that you’re apparently supposed to make a new separate `newtype` for each different way to implement an instance for your same type. Which is just silly.)

Comment: This answer completely misses an explanation of what "Non type-variable argument in the constraint: `Num [b]`" actually means! Or rather it misidentifies it as a confusing way for GHC to say "lists aren't numbers"; the actual error message GHC would print out for that would be something about not finding an `Num` instance for  `[b]` (which still isn't the *most* newbie-friendly way to say it, but it's pretty comprehensible if you know what `Num` is and what instances are). "Non type-variable argument in the constraint: `Num [b]`" is a completely different issue.